# React Native seeks wrong folder and throws "Unable to resolve module. None of these files exist" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

There is a framework which is intended to make React Native to work in Linux desktop.
I forked it to [my repo](https://gitlab.com/react-native-linux/react-native-linux), since original author recently stopped managed it.
They were still using React Native 0.60.6, so I upgraded it to 0.63.4.

But when I ran `react-native run-linux` command, The window became red, and said `Failed to load source code`.
And this is what terminal said:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo from /home/myname/Desktop/foo/node_modules/react-native/index.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo(.native|.desktop-qt.js|.native.js|.js|.desktop-qt.json|.native.json|.json|.desktop-qt.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.desktop-qt.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo/index(.native|.desktop-qt.js|.native.js|.js|.desktop-qt.json|.native.json|.json|.desktop-qt.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.desktop-qt.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
     |                                       ^
  14 | import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
  15 | import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
  16 | import typeof CheckBox from './Libraries/Components/CheckBox/CheckBox';
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/myname/Desktop/foo/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:168:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/myname/Desktop/foo/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:353:43)
    at Object.resolve (/home/myname/Desktop/foo/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:271:42)
    at resolve (/home/myname/Desktop/foo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:571:33)
    at /home/myname/Desktop/foo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:587:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/home/myname/Desktop/foo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:586:33)
    at /home/myname/Desktop/foo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/myname/Desktop/foo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

The strangest thing of that error message is, React Native is looking for module in `node_modules/react-native/`.
modules which ends with `.desktop-qt.js` are placed in `node_modules/react-native-linux/`.

So, the cause of error must be seeking modules in wrong folder. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revoked to 0.60.6 and it solved. Maybe updating script was a problem.